# Keystone GET user email

Tags: rest, openstack, devstack, keystone

Hello I have been trying to get my contact information using the REST API that Keystone has without success

I'm using an unscoped token and i'm getting a 401 Unauthorized even with the admin user, and i'm authenticating against the port 5000 and querying through the 35357 the user's info so at the end I would like to have the email address, this is the curl command that I use:

```
curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Auth-Token: PKIZ_eJxVlEmPqzgQgO..' http://192.168.44.132:35357/v2.0/users/my_user
```

This is a fresh devstack installation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this thing working It was the token I forgot to add to the 'tenantName': 'admin'

Old

{ 'auth'=> { 'passwordCredentials' => { 'username' => username, 'password' => password } } }

New

{ 'auth'=> { 'tenantName' => 'admin', 'passwordCredentials' => { 'username' => username, 'password' => password } } }